# Receiving Emails in Python

Tags: python, email, imaplib

I am trying to receive emails on my Pi, so far I am receiving the emails from my inbox from gmail however I am trying to receive them without all the added content such as the message ID and content type. Im looking for pure email body text. I've got this so far....

```
 import imaplib

 mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')

 mail.login('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxx')

 mail.list

 mail.select("inbox")


 obj, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')

 for num in data [0].split():

 typ, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')

 print 'Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, data[0][1])

 mail.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `'BODY[1]'` as the string as opposed to `'(RFC822)'`.

What `'BODY[1]'` does is that it specifies that you only want the text/plain portion of the email. You can find inside this document [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501), which explains in detail FETCH commands under section 6.4.5, or page 53.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I got loads of errors with this :(

File "email.py", line 9 in <module>
 type, data = mail.fetch(num, 'BODY[1]')

and a bunch of other errors in line 455 and 1087

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? I edited my answer to be less specific (I don't have as much experience using Python 2.x, mostly use Python 3.4). However, the string specification should be correct.

Comment: Im getting a fetch command error: BAD ['Could not parse command'] but it also doesn't like the BODY[1] edit

Comment: Fantastic Answer. Great link too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I made the rookie mistake of naming my file email.py and also not importing email!

Thank you.